# Entity Framwork Core Add-Migration fails

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

I'm trying to use Ef Core in my project.

The structure is a little different, in the sense that I'm not using EfCore insite the WebApi.csproj. In fact I have a different dll. and a DependenciesResolver.dll that handles all my dependency injection.

In my EfCore.dll I've installed both

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Now when I try to run the command (the dll in which I'm running is the EfCore.dll)

```
Add-Migration Name
```

I get this :

> An error occurred while accessing the IWebHost on class 'Program'.
>   Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object. Unable to create an
>   object of type 'StoreContext'. Add an implementation of
>   'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory' to the project, or see
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for additional patterns
>   supported at design time.

The structure of the sln is like this

WebApi | EfCore.dll | DependencyResolver.dll and I want to keep it this way, don't want to permit using EfCore in my WebApi.

What is the resolution for this issue ?

If this helps within the EfCore.dll I have this.

```
 public sealed partial class StoreContext : DbContext, IStoreContext
    {
        private string _connectionString;

        public StoreContext(string connectionString) : base()
        {
            _connectionString = connectionString;

            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        /// db.tbls
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.AddOrderConfiguration();
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
        }
    }
```

which is called by DependencyResolver like this

```
        private DependenciesResolver RegisterInfrastructure()
        {
            _serviceCollection.AddScoped<StoreContext>(factory => new StoreContext(_connectionString));

            return this;
        }
```

and the DependencyResolver  is then called by the WebApi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please have a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation

The error message clearly specifies the EF Core tools can't create an instance of your Context at design-time.

If you can define a constructor with no parameters for your StoreContext that would work, otherwise you need tell the tools how to create an instance of your context at design-time by defining a class that implements the IDesignTimeDbContextFactory interface.